# Assertion failed on CODY mathworks

Tags: matlab

Question is Problem 23, finding the perfect squares.  My code is shown below:

```
function b = isItSquare1(a)
if any(ismember(a,a.^2))==0
    b='false';
else 
    b='true';
end
end
```

I am getting `Assertion failed` whereas using this function is correct:

```
function b = isItSquare(a)
c=0;i=1;
b='false';

while c==0&i<=length(a)
if length(find(a==a(i)^2))~=0

b='yes';

c=1;
end
i=i+1;

end

b
end
```

Cody accepts the answer I am unable to understand why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The assertions are published, right? So you could run them yourself and check which assertion fails, and why.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has boolean types (the type is called "logical" in MATLAB), `true` and `false` (often denoted by `1` and `0`). This is *not* the same as the strings `'true'` / `'false'`. Compare the following:

```
>> x = 'true'
>> y = true
```

[image: workspace]

These are two fundamentally different things. If you compare these values using `==`:

```
>> 'true' == true    
ans =
     0     0     0     0
```

then MATLAB handles `'true'` as vector of characters and compares each value to `true`, which return `false=0`.
However

```
>> true == 1
ans =
     1
```

Now, to your problem: the first test suite on Cody is

```
a = [2 3 4];
assert(isequal(isItSquared(a),true))
```

i.e. the output must be `true` and not `'true'`. Thus, replace `'true'` by `true` and `'false'` by `false` in your code, and the assertions should pass.

A small hint: Any comparison operator, e.g. `==`, `~=`, `<`, ... automatically creates a logical (`true` or `false`) as output, for example:

```
>> x = (1 == 2)
x = 
    0
```